# How to wait for item to be removed from list

Tags: protractor

I am trying to delete and Item from the list, it takes long time in application to delete this element, so I want to wait until this element is deleted and then verify that this item is not present on the page.

`this.GroupList = element.all(by.repeater("Group in GroupList | orderBy: order"));`

Now I delete an element from the above list based on its Name `getAttribute('aria-label')`, How can I use ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf  OR ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf to wait till one element from the list is removed from DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to this specific repeater item, you can use [`stalenessOf` Expected Condition](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf), for instance:

```
// page object
this.GroupList = element.all(by.repeater("Group in GroupList"));

// test
var itemToBeDeleted = pageObject.GroupList.get(5);

// delete an item here

browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(itemToBeDeleted), 5000);
```

Note that you don't need the "orderBy" part in the repeater locator.

---

Another idea would be to wait for the count to decrease by one with a custom expected condition:

```
function waitForCount(elementArrayFinder, count) {
    return function () {
        return elementArrayFinder.count(function (actualCount) {
            return actualCount === count;
        });
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
pageObject.GroupList.count().then(function (countBefore) {
    // delete item here

    browser.wait(waitForCount(pageObject.GroupList, countBefore - 1)); 
});
```

Comment: to identify and delete this element I use its Name and delete it, how can I use expected condition to identify this element. `exports.DeleteGroupByDisplayName = function(displayName) {
this.GroupList.filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getAttribute('aria-label').then(function(text) {
            return text.toUpperCase() === displayName.toUpperCase();
        });
    }).then(function(filteredElements) {
        filteredElements[0].click();
    });
this.DeleteBtn.click();
this.DeleteConf.click();
};
`

Comment: @ssharma I think you should be able to return `filteredElements[0]` from the `then()` which would make `DeleteGroupByDisplayName` return an `ElementFinder` which you may pass to `stalenessOf`..